# Jasmine2 is not a valid framework error

Tags: angularjs, visual-studio-2015, protractor, jasmine2.0

I recently followed a tutorial on running protractor tests inside vs.  To my surprise it works however i had to remove jasmine2 as the framework in the conf file or I would get this error

```
config.framework jasmine2 is not a valid framework.
```

This is also my first time running the chromedriver through vs and it cannot sendKeys as i was before.
Ex: `this.passwordTextField.clear().sendKeys(browser.params.password);`

I'm not sure how to get protractor to recognize jasmine2.  I have installed jasmine manually also with the --save-dev tag.  Protractor is at version 2.5.1
and jasmine is at 2.1.4

Any idea what is going on?  Or if there is a better way of running protractor in vs?

I'm using this tutorial which didn't exactly work so I borrowed her sample code and edited that, that worked.  Here is the site:
https://misaxionsoftware.wordpress.com/2014/01/30/angularjs-protractor-visual-studio-super-dry/

Comment: are you using npm to install your dependencies?

Comment: @jack yeah I did use npm

Comment: how is your protractor configuration? are you running any grunt/gulp task?, what do you mean with "installed jasmine manually?"

Answer (score 0):

This error can only happen if `protractor` <= 1.5.0 is used. Check if tests are executed by the correct `protractor` executable. FYI, [this is where it fails](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/1.5.0/lib/runner.js#L276-L288).

For instance, you may have an old globally installed protractor which is used instead of the one installed locally inside project's `node_modules`.

Or, what I've also seen in practice, the protractor executable located at `.bin/protractor` was updated by one of the packages that has protractor as a dependency (like `grunt-protractor-runner`, for instance).

Comment: from what i see my global protractor is also an upgraded version

Comment: @NicolePhillips as per that tutorial, `.bin/protractor` is used - I'm pretty sure this one is old. Updated the answer.

Comment: do you have a min for a chat?

Comment: @NicolePhillips yup, sure.